# Which sonar-maven-plugin version to use?

Tags: maven-plugin, sonarqube

I am wondering which sonar-maven-plugin in which version I should use.
As far as I know there is a [org.codehaus.mojo](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin) version and two org.codehaus.sonar versions ([sonar-maven3-plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/master/sonar-maven3-plugin), [sonar-maven-plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/master/sonar-maven-plugin)).

As far as I understand the sonar-maven3-plugin is now deprecated and the org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin should be used instead. However those org.codehaus.sonar version are tied to a certain version of the sonar server, therefore it makes probably no sense to use them directly.
To be able to deal with this there is the org.codehaus.**mojo**:sonar-maven-plugin which checks which sonar version the server has and from there checks which org.codehaus.**sonar**:sonar-maven-plugin to use.

So in order to have a maven pom that is independent of the Sonar Server Version one should probably use the `org.sonar.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:RELEASE` version to be safe.

Did I get this right?

Any further things to consider?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As described in the [documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-ProjectanalyzedwithMaven3) (see "Project analyzed with Maven 3"), the plugin you have to use is `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin`, not the internal one(s).

Comment: And, how do we correlate the version numbers between the org.codehaus.sonar and org.codehaus.mojo sonar-maven-plugins?

Comment: Let's say that the "org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin" used to be a facade plugin to the internal ones in order to not have dependencies to SonarQube API. It detects which version of the internal plugins to use thanks to a WS call to the server to know which version of SonarQube is installed. I say "used to be a facade" because in upcoming SQ 5.2, the internal plugins will no longer be required and therefore are removed from the code base.

Comment: How about the `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin`? Is that a Maven2 only plugin?

Comment: Now, it's: [org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

When we were using sonarserver ver 3.7.1 we used to have org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin.
Once we migrated from Sonar Server to SonarQube server 4.5+ onwards, we need to use org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin.
Currently in our project , we need to compile our code with jdk 6(as it is old project) and run the sonarqube server ver 4.5.7 analysis with java 7
so with java 6 we run the command `mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:prepare-agent install` and while running the sonar analysis we change the jvm to java 7 and execute the command `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar -Dsonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=true`