# Maven can't resolve sonar-maven-plugin version 5.1.2

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, sonarqube-5.0

We have Sonar and Jenkins located on the same machine, and Sonar analysis is run as Jenkins job post step. Jenkins jobs are built with Maven 3.0.5.

Everything was fine until we updated Sonar from 4.5.x to 5.1.2 yesterday.

After update sonar step failed with exception:

> **org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:** Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project TestApplication: Can not execute Sonar
>
> **Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:** Can not execute Sonar
>
> **Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException:** Plugin org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:5.1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:jar:5.1.2
>
> **Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException:** Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:jar:5.1.2
>
> **Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException:** Failure to find org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:pom:5.1.2 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

We figured out that there is actually 5.1 version of org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin, but no 5.1.2 in maven repo.

**Fix:**

We managed to fix it with forcing org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin version to 2.6 through  in our pom file, as advised on official [Analyzing with Sonar](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven#AnalyzingwithMaven-HowtoFixVersionofMavenPlugin) doc

But since we have dozens of projects, there should be better solution rather than changing every single project's pom files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, simple solution found:

In the maven repository (.m2) it was cached that latest version of org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin is 2.0, even though the latest one is 2.6. (in file `.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin/maven-metadata-central.xml`)

The old version differs a lot from the new one in the way it works (see [Which sonar-maven-plugin version to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980521/which-sonar-maven-plugin-version-to-use))

We removed .m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin directory, so that newer version is downloaded.

Comment: Best is to define the used version by your build in your pom file.

Comment: I disagree: imagine we've got a lot of successfully running jobs. That would be bad to change all of them. And you have to do it every time new version is out.

Comment: If you don't do it your success is depending on the local storage (repository in other words).

Comment: I agree that the best solution is to change the jobs.  As Anton says though, when there are a lot of working projects sharing a SonarQube instance it's just not feasible to force everyone to upgrade at the same time.  There has to be some backwards compatibility so the current jobs continue to run until the owning developers can make the needed update.